# CMake recursive include of modules

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to use the CMake `INCLUDE` command the same way as in C++.

In all my projects I have to make the same includes:

Example: CMakeLists.txt for "MyApplication"

```
INCLUDE("FindMyBase")
INCLUDE("FindMyGtk")
```

In this example **FindMyGtk** already has "FindMyBase" in it. 
So why do I need to include **FindMyBase** in **MyApplication**? 
Is there a way once one .cmake file has been included that it stays available for all other projects in the chain below?

- Update 1: The idea is to avoid searching every time for MyBase if it was already found once.
- Update 2: The objective is also to reduce the number of includes. In my example from 2 to 1, but if you have 10 includes then you can reduce them to just 2 if these 2 depend on the other 8.

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what exactly needs to be included multiple times?

Comment: The Find<Package>.cmake modules are usually not used directly, but by calling find_package(<Package>). This should take care of duplicated calls. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html

Comment: I've added a little more info to my answer; does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have also updated my question.

Comment: So as per your Update 2, this *is* what happens.  If you include A and inside A it includes B, then there's no need to include B explicitly again.

Answer (score 2):

It pretty much does do that.  I visualise `include` as if you'd pasted the contents of the include file directly into the CMakeLists.txt file where you called it.

In your case, "FindMyBase" is called twice.  This often doesn't matter - e.g. if the include file only defines functions or macros it's safe to include multiple times.

If the included file searches for components using CMake's collection of `find_XXX` functions, then these already do what you want.  The result of the search is cached.  On subsequent invocations, if this cached result shows that the component has already been found, no further searching is done.

If you want (or have) to avoid including the same file multiple times, you can add include guards to the top of the file in a similar way to C++ include guards:

```
if(FindMyBaseIncluded)
  return()
endif()
set(FindMyBaseIncluded TRUE)
```

That way, including the file multiple times is almost cost-free.

Comment: So in each Find.cmake file I need to put INCLUDE(Find) for all the dependencies. This is what I am trying right now.

Comment: Note that CMake 3.10 introduced an [`include_guard`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/include_guard.html#command:include_guard) command to relieve you from having to write your include guards by hand.